# Selected null-value for 1:N Doctrine relation in EntityType-field

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-forms

I got incidents which have a reference to a risk.

I am using Symfony 2.6 and Doctrine ORM entities with the following rather symbolic entities:

```
class Incident
{
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $date;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Risk")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="risk_id")
     */
    private $risk;
}

class Risk
{
    private $id;
    private $level;
    private $name;
}
```

The `risks`-Table has data like:

```
id  level   name
1   0       none
2   2       low
3   1       very low
4   5       moderate
5   10      high
```

For the incidents I got a form-type like this:

```
class IncidentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
[...]
            ->add('risk', 'entity', [
                'class' => 'Model:Risk',
                'property' => 'name',
                'empty_data' => null,
                'empty_value' => 'not assessed',
                'expanded' => true,
                'required' => [true|false](see below),
            ])
[...]
}
```

So my incidents risk can be 'not assessed'. That is when there is no risk set (=`null`). To keep my model clean I would not want to have a row with a level of -1 and a name of 'not assessed'.

My form works as expected, missing one tiny detail: when the `risk` is `null`, my list of radiobuttons has no value selected. This happens regardless of the value of the `'required'`-option.

For a null-value I get:

```
( ) not assessed
( ) none
( ) very low
[...]
```

I would want:

```
(x) not assessed
( ) none
( ) very low
[...]
```

I guess that behaviour is just fine for a (not expanded) drop-down field.

Is there a way to have the `'placeholder'`/`'empty_value'`-option of my radiobuttons selected when the data-value is `null`?

Comment: have you tried doing `'empty_data'  => null, 'empty_value' => "not assessed",` ? Actually `'empty_value' => "not assessed"` should to the trick, and you don't need placeholder.

Comment: I wonder how I missed that. Yet there is no difference in the rendered markup. The 'not assessed' is still not selected. I corrected my question, dropped the prototype.

Comment: how do you render that in your template ?

Comment: I am rendering using `{{ form_row(form.risk) }}`.

Comment: I just checked that and it works, the first value is selected when the `risk` is empty and when using `'class' => 'Model:Risk',
                'property' => 'name',
                'empty_data' => null,
                'empty_value' => 'not assessed',
                'expanded' => true,
                'required' => true`. Remove cache?

Comment: Thank you very much for checking. It won't work for me. I will start to isolate that bit in a new project and keep this page updated...

Comment: I could confirm it working using a fresh Symfony 2.7.10 setup. Thank you for your help, @takeit . Rephrase your comment into a short answer and I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your `risk` field you should do:

```
class IncidentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
        [...]
            ->add('risk', 'entity', [
                'class' => 'Model:Risk',
                'property' => 'name',
                'empty_data' => null, 
                'empty_value' => 'not assessed', 
                'expanded' => true, 
                'required' => true
            ])
    [...]
    }
}
```

I just checked that and it works, the first value is selected when the `risk` is empty and when using the above code. Note I added `'empty_data' => null, 'empty_value' => 'not assessed',` and removed `placeholder`.

Comment: My final findings: It is working as expected in Symfony 2.7.10; It is not working in Symfony 2.7.4

Comment: You can check the changelog: http://symfony.com/blog/category/releases and compare what has been changed exactly. Maybe it will give you a hint.

Comment: I guess the relevant change was introduced with 2.7.10 or 2.7.8. I see it got taken care of and will upgrade. Thank you for your help, once again.

Answer (score -1):

that works but is not a good solution... what would happens if your first value is dynamic?

Comment: This is rather a comment than an answer. I know that you don't have enough rep for this but that are the rules...